# Cast this to void*&

Tags: c++, casting, parameter-passing, this, void-pointers

I have a method which accept `void*&` as an argument and I'd like to pass `this` as a parameter.

Example:

```
struct A
{
    void foo()
    {
        bar((void*&)this);
    }
private:
    void bar(void*& p) {}
};
```

I have the following compiler error:

```
cast_this.cpp: In member function 'void A::foo()':
cast_this.cpp:5:14: error: invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type 'A*' to type 'void*&'
  bar((void*&)this);
              ^
```

Is there any way to cast the `this` pointer?

**EDIT:**
Trying with `bar((void* const &)this);` gives:

```
cast_this.cpp: In member function 'void A::foo()':

cast_this.cpp:5:25: error: binding 'void* const' to reference of type 'void*&' discards qualifiers
  bar((void* const &)this);
                         ^
cast_this.cpp:8:10: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'void A::bar(void*&)'
     void bar(void*& p) {}
          ^
```

Comment: C++ goes to reasonable lengths to keep you safe. You'll need an expression like @Piotr provided to shoot yourself in the foot. But understand that you *will* shoot yourself in the foot with code like that. `bar` has a signature that means it's changing the `void*`, but you cannot change `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments on your question, you can use a `const` qualification (because `this` is effectively `const`) - but you need it for both the cast and the parameter:

```
    bar((void* const &)this);

    void bar(void* const & p) {}
```

(And in fact, as per comment below, you *don't* actually need the cast once you change the function signature). This causes a temporary to be initialized with the value of `this` and bound to the `p` parameter of `bar` (thanks to M.M. for explanation).

Of course if you can change the signature of `bar` in that way then you may as well make it accept a plain `void *` instead:

```
    bar(this);

    void bar(void* p) {}
```

Alternatively, save the pointer value to another variable:

```
    void * t = this;
    bar(t);
```

Note that the current signature of `bar` implies that it might change the value of `t` before returning.

Comment: note: there is no reason to prefer `void * const &p` to `void *p`. Also, with that change to function signature you do not need the cast in the function call.

Comment: @M.M true apparently, though I firmly believe you _should_ need a cast for that particular conversion, especially since IIUC it leads to a potential strict aliasing violation.

Comment: There's no aliasing violation: it creates a "temporary" of type `void * const` initialized from `this`, and the reference binds to the temporary. (reference binding either binds directly or binds to a temporary -- it never binds to the "wrong type" unless you explicitly cast to a reference to the wrong type).  So omitting the cast in fact removes the possibility of causing an aliasing violation by using the wrong cast

Comment: @M.M however, a quick experiment seems to indicate that a temporary is created and bound whether the cast is used or not.

Comment: Yeah, in the case of builtin types (e.g. pointers) , a reference binding to a prvalue always binds to a copy.  Only for class types can it bind directly to a pre-existing object

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a prvalue, it cannot be bound to a non-const lvalue reference.  There is also an issue about the type but the value category is a showstopper so we don't need to go into that.

You will have to write something like:

```
void *ptr = this;
bar(ptr);
```

The function signature being `void *&` suggests that the function might change its argument. The address of an object cannot be changed so this suggests that the function doesn't do what you think it does, or you have some misconception about the effect of the function.